# $RANDOM, not so random

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, zsh

I want to print out a random number and encrypt it, like so: `echo $RANDOM | sha256sum`.

I would expect this to take the standard output of `echo $RANDOM` and pipe it into the encryption function. However doing this twice in a row (or however many times) , gives me the same output.

Here's what I know:

- `echo $RANDOM` works. I do in fact get a new number at every print.
- Calling `exec zsh` to reset my shell, and then running the code generates a new random output (that keeps repeating).

This is obviously not a huge problem for, but I am really curious to find out why this is happening.

I am using Zsh. Switching to Bash also gives me different results. This seems to be Zsh-related then. I'd still like to know why. Can someone explain why I am not getting a random output?

Comment: What is your shell? `zsh` or `bash`. In `bash` I get different results every time.

Comment: I am using zsh. Switcing to bash also gives me different results. This seems to be zsh-related then. I'd still like to know why.

Comment: It might be a bug in zsh...  I tested it on bash and it works

Comment: In the linked duplicate it's important `$( )` runs a subshell. In your case `echo $RANDOM` in `echo $RANDOM | sha256sum` is run in a subshell. The mechanism of getting identical random numbers is the same.

Comment: Note that if you are actually performing cryptographic operations, you want to be very particular about what (P)RNGs you use and where, so be sure to read up on the documentation.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/ feels relevant.